# How can i find the current divider in the right resistor valued as "2 * R1"?

Tags: current, resistors, current-source, current-divider

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frqhzy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My intention here is to find the current in the right resistor valued as "2*R1" using the current-divider formula. I don't know how to interpret the connections between these resistors.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of tidying your drawing. You can't work out the actual current since we don't have the value of R1 or Ia but you should be able to see R2 and R3 are in series and can be replaced by a single resistor.  What would this resistor be and can you work out the current that would be in it in terms of R1 and Ia?

Comment: I just needed the current in order to find the algebraic expression of the tension "Voc".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a homework question you just get a hint:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsKSG3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Original schematic. (b) Rearranged schematic.*

You should be able to work it out from Figure 1b.